# How to structure my sport manager Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm building a sport manager app that let the users create their own competitions and update the match results to be consults for other participants.

I read a lot about how flat the database (I come from SQL :-) and saw many video tutorials from the Firebase Team.

At this point I have this structure:

```
{sport-manager :
    ...
    groups : {
        "groupId1" : {
            competitionId : "competitionId1"
            name : "Group A",
            type : "LEAGUE"
        },
        "groupId2" : {
            competitionId : "competitionId1"
            name : "West playoofs",
            type : "PLAYOFFS"
        },
        ...
    },
    players : {
        "playerId1" : {
            birthday : 351408600000,
            firsName : "Jhon",
            lastName : "Doe",
            shirtNumber : 0,
            teamId : "teamId1"
        },
        ...
    },
    teams : {
        "teamId1" : {
            competitionId : "competitionId1"
            name : "Team 1",
            },
        ...
    },
    teamGroupStats : {
        "groupId1" : {
            "teamId1" : {
                goalsAgainst: 0,
                goalsFavor: 0,
                matchesDraw: 0,
                matchesLoss: 0,
                matchesPlayed: 0,
                matchesWin: 0,
                points: 0,
                teamName: "Team 1",
            },
            "teamId2" : {
            ...
            },
            ...
        },
        "groupId2" : {
            "teamId2" : {
            ...
            },
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This structure let me make queries to populate a ListView adapter with the data of all the teams that are part of a group in this way:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query groupQuery = mDatabase.child("teamGroupStats").child("groupId1")
```

Or when I have to get the player from determinated team:

```
Query playersQuery = mDatabase.child("players").orderByChild("teamId").equalTo("teamId1");
```

So far, so good. My problem come when I have to delete a team from this structure. For avoid integrity problems I use multipath update to delete all.

- A team can have one or more players
- A team can be part of one or more groups.

With that in mind, I can delete any teams with all his players.

```
Map<String, Object> deleteMap = new HashMap<>();
deleteMap.put("teams/teamId1", null);

Query playersQuery = mDatabase.child("players").orderByChild("teamId").equalTo("teamId1");
playersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot playerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            deleteMap.put("players/" + playerSnapshot.getKey(), null);
        }

        // Delete all in one call!
        mDatabase.updateChildren(deleteMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

How I can make a query to get all the paths with "teamId1" has secundary key in the structure "teamGroupStats"? 
His this structure good for the use I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found one solution. I modified my database to store all the groups Id's where the team belong inside the Team structure.

```
teams : {
    "teamId1" : {
        competitionId : "competitionId1"
        groups : {
            "groupId1" : true,
            "groupId6" : true,
            ...
        },
        name : "Team 1",
        },
    ...
```

With that information, I can add an inner ValueEventListener in the playersQuery's listener and make the update/delete.

```
public static void deleteTeam(final String teamId){
    Map<String, Object> deleteMap = new HashMap<>();
    deleteMap.put("teams/" + teamId, null);

    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query playersQuery = mDatabase.child("players").orderByChild("teamId").equalTo(teamId);
    playersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot playerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String playerId = playerSnapshot.getKey();
                deleteMap.put("players/" + playerId, null);
            }

            mDatabase.child("teams").child(teamId).child("groups")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot groupSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String groupId = groupSnapshot.getKey();
                        deleteMap.put("teamGroupStats/" + groupId + "/" + teamId, null);
                    }

                    // Delete all in one call!
                    mDatabase.updateChildren(deleteMap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
}
```

I wasn't very sure about the inner listener, and I had to made a little change to my database structure, but this works fine.

If anybody knows a better way to do this, I'm open to read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your database is very well structured. Regarding your question, you cannot get all paths as you say. What can you do, is to delete data in the same way as you add it. So in order to delete all data i recomand you using this method:

```
private static void deleteTeam(String teamId) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/teams/" + teamId, null);
    map.put("/teamGroupStats/groupId1/" + teamId, null);
    map.put("/players/playerId1/teamId/", null);
    databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
}
```

A more generic method will be:

```
private static void deleteTeam(String reference, String teamId) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(reference, null);
    databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
}
```

If you need to query the database to get additional data, use `getRef()` method to get the reference and pass those values to the second method.

All your data will be deleted at once atomically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem it's that I don't have only one player in each team or a team are in only one group. I can't use your method because I don't know the list of players in each team or the groups where the team belong until I make a query to the database (and the asynchronous call doesn't help to do that)

Comment: In this case, make the query, find all the data that you need and pass that data to the method. I have updaed my answer with a more generic method.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that generic method doesn't work. You are populating only one pair "path, null" in the map and that don't make a multi-path delete. The way for delete a team and all his players that I show in the post works fine, my problem it's get the secondary key (team ID) from "teamGroupStats". If that can't be done, maybe my structure have a problem.

Comment: To have multi-path then just use the map to add the needed paths, and in the end just call `databaseReference.updateChildren(map);`.